# Sorting large array in power automate

Tags: power-automate, rpa

I have around 700 resources of which I have metrics array containing 1300+ values , float values

I am trying to compute 80th percentile of this large array of values in Power automate.

My issue is its taking 10-15 min per case, also I have to construct a separate array as my source array sometimes has non existing metric property

my source array looks like this (having 1392 elements)

```
{
"data":[
{
"timestamp":"2022-11-11T07:00:00Z",
"average":34.4
},
 {
 "timestamp": "2022-12-10T06:00:00Z"
}
]}
```

I tried various ways

1. I made another array first , wherever average was not present , I added a zero to result array
2. then sorted this array ( via sort expression)
3. applied formula for 80th percentile to get right index
4. extracted that index value from array.

Step 1 is taking a lot of time unfortunately , Apply to each is being used with max concurrency.

Please advise how we can make this faster.

Thanks

Comment: The advanced data operations connector will be able to help you, it can perform your task in bulk. Take a look … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/connectors/advanceddataoperatio/ … they’re in preview so are happy to lend a hand if you reach out to them.

Comment: Further to that, when you provide the data to the API, it doesn't have to be balanced, i.e. the fields do not need to be the same item on item.  It will find all fields and balance out the data in the background before processing it.

Comment: Thanks @Skin , are there any examples? Unfortunately do not understand how to use for my particular use case

Comment: There’s documentation here … https://www.statesolutions.com.au/ … you can literally sign up for a trial, email them your payload and they’ll help you where they can.

Comment: Here’s a thought, can you provide your payload in its entirety to your question? If so, I can have a go for you, I have a subscription.

Comment: Hey thats cool, the payload has 1392 elements, would it be supported here

Comment: Yes, it would only take a few seconds to process as well.

Comment: am hitting the character limit here, let me see how I can share

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250366/discussion-between-skin-and-just-another-developer).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector.

There's an expert function that allows you to run an SQL statement over your dataset.  You could filter this data further to everything above the 80th percentile by simply adding a WHERE clause at the end.

This is the flow I tested with ...

[image: Flow]

... so in that single step, it will do everything you want it to.

This is the SQL statement supplied in the screenshot above ...

```
SELECT *, PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY [Average]) AS [Percentile] 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM [Data] WHERE [Average] IS NOT NULL
) AS [NewData] 
ORDER BY [Percentile] DESC
```

**Note:** *To make sure it's producing the correct result, I've removed all items that have a null `average` value.*

This is the resulting flow which took a mere **6 seconds** to run ...

[image: Result]

... and here is the resulting JSON array with the data ...

```
[
    {
        "average": 22.674375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T07:30:00",
        "Percentile": 1
    },
    {
        "average": 22.1976666666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T19:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.985915492957746
    },
    {
        "average": 22.1189166666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T07:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.971830985915493
    },
    {
        "average": 21.85075,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T08:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.957746478873239
    },
    {
        "average": 21.2718020833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T00:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.943661971830986
    },
    {
        "average": 21.2456145833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T16:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.929577464788732
    },
    {
        "average": 21.1545520833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T09:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.915492957746479
    },
    {
        "average": 21.09884375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T15:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.901408450704225
    },
    {
        "average": 21.0786145833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T09:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.887323943661972
    },
    {
        "average": 20.9709270833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T19:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.873239436619718
    },
    {
        "average": 20.7876979166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T06:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.859154929577465
    },
    {
        "average": 20.7539270833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T05:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.845070422535211
    },
    {
        "average": 20.724375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T16:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.830985915492958
    },
    {
        "average": 20.7124479166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T15:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.816901408450704
    },
    {
        "average": 20.7032708333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T13:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.802816901408451
    },
    {
        "average": 20.6885104166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T08:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.788732394366197
    },
    {
        "average": 20.6832083333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T13:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.774647887323944
    },
    {
        "average": 20.6540208333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T10:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.76056338028169
    },
    {
        "average": 20.6439166666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T04:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.746478873239437
    },
    {
        "average": 20.59803125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T07:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.732394366197183
    },
    {
        "average": 20.5738125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T06:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.71830985915493
    },
    {
        "average": 20.5018645833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T00:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.704225352112676
    },
    {
        "average": 20.500875,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T14:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.690140845070423
    },
    {
        "average": 20.46678125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T16:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.676056338028169
    },
    {
        "average": 20.43015625,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T07:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.661971830985916
    },
    {
        "average": 20.4273020833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T11:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.647887323943662
    },
    {
        "average": 20.4161041666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T21:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.633802816901409
    },
    {
        "average": 20.3894791666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T10:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.619718309859155
    },
    {
        "average": 20.3787604166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T17:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.605633802816901
    },
    {
        "average": 20.3724270833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T09:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.591549295774648
    },
    {
        "average": 20.3398333333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T12:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.577464788732394
    },
    {
        "average": 20.2841145833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T08:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.563380281690141
    },
    {
        "average": 20.2529449152542,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T13:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.549295774647887
    },
    {
        "average": 20.2286875,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T17:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.535211267605634
    },
    {
        "average": 20.22403125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T14:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.52112676056338
    },
    {
        "average": 20.2209375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T11:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.507042253521127
    },
    {
        "average": 20.1904895833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T06:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.492957746478873
    },
    {
        "average": 20.1900729166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T12:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.47887323943662
    },
    {
        "average": 20.148125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T01:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.464788732394366
    },
    {
        "average": 20.129625,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T23:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.450704225352113
    },
    {
        "average": 20.0616666666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T14:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.436619718309859
    },
    {
        "average": 20.0449895833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T10:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.422535211267606
    },
    {
        "average": 20.0333645833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T12:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.408450704225352
    },
    {
        "average": 19.9994583333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T21:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.394366197183099
    },
    {
        "average": 19.9905,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T11:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.380281690140845
    },
    {
        "average": 19.9578125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T09:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.366197183098592
    },
    {
        "average": 19.94271875,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T05:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.352112676056338
    },
    {
        "average": 19.9379895833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T10:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.338028169014084
    },
    {
        "average": 19.91659375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T18:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.323943661971831
    },
    {
        "average": 19.8985104166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T01:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.309859154929577
    },
    {
        "average": 19.8849479166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T14:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.295774647887324
    },
    {
        "average": 19.8658229166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T15:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.28169014084507
    },
    {
        "average": 19.85403125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T18:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.267605633802817
    },
    {
        "average": 19.8325,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T22:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.253521126760563
    },
    {
        "average": 19.7983958333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T04:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.23943661971831
    },
    {
        "average": 19.7926145833333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T15:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.225352112676056
    },
    {
        "average": 19.780875,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T20:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.211267605633803
    },
    {
        "average": 19.7798333333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T23:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.197183098591549
    },
    {
        "average": 19.76359375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T11:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.183098591549296
    },
    {
        "average": 19.7552604166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T08:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.169014084507042
    },
    {
        "average": 19.695125,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T13:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.154929577464789
    },
    {
        "average": 19.50509375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T20:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.140845070422535
    },
    {
        "average": 19.4972291666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T16:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.126760563380282
    },
    {
        "average": 19.4948541666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-11T22:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.112676056338028
    },
    {
        "average": 19.4910104166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T12:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.0985915492957746
    },
    {
        "average": 19.4601979166667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T03:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.0845070422535211
    },
    {
        "average": 19.2794375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T03:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.0704225352112676
    },
    {
        "average": 15.9129791666667,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T02:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.0563380281690141
    },
    {
        "average": 15.20909375,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T02:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.0422535211267606
    },
    {
        "average": 11.3621875,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T17:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0.028169014084507
    },
    {
        "average": 9.31830208333333,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T17:30:00",
        "Percentile": 0.0140845070422535
    },
    {
        "average": 9.08600961538462,
        "timeStamp": "2022-11-12T18:00:00",
        "Percentile": 0
    }
]
```

It should be noted that the **`Expert`** function is a part of the `Standard` pricing model.  It's very affordable but whether you deem that so or not is very much relative.

Comment: Hey Skin, many thanks for taking so much time and effort. Looks pretty useful but am not sure of teh cost perspective here, will be great to explore this one

Comment: Of course, cost is always a factor. I can only leave that part to you to decide on but you’re welcome.